# Google Sheets IMPORTXML Twitter //div[@data-testid='tweetText']

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to Google Sheets `IMPORTXML` the text contained within elements with XPath

`//div[@data-testid='tweetText']` but I get content empty

I have my formula like

```
 =IMPORTXML("https://twitter.com/hashtag/NoCode","//div[@data-testid='tweetText']")
```

I tried the XPath variation `"//article[@data-testid='tweet']"`, but same error

I also tried the XPaths I got from Chrome Dev Tools:

**XPath:**

`//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/section/div/div/div[5]/div/div/article`

**AND FULL XPath:**

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div/article
```

But I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the URL you provided, and I was requested to sign-in to see the content. Remember that `importhtml()`, `importxml()`, `importdata()`, and `importfeed()` functions only work with public pages that do not require signing in or other forms of authentication.

Also you need to take in consideration that even if it's a public page, if the content is created dynamically by JavaScript,   it cannot be accessed with those functions. The website's owner may also purposefully have prevented web scraping.

You can review if the website is generating data using Javascript by [disabling this feature in the browser](https://www.impressivewebs.com/how-to-disable-javascript-in-almost-any-browser/), and reload the page. When I did the test, I got this message.

[image: page error]

As a workaround maybe you can use another tool specifically for web scraping. I found this software recommendation [page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/55071/web-scraping-tools-and-software-available-for-free), with some information about it.

Or you can create a new question for more updated information in the same section of StackExchange.

Comment: With formula =IMPORTXML("https://twitter.com/hashtag/NoCode","//@href") I was able to import all links in the page, so login issues are not in my radar