# Importxml on G Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, html-table, google-sheets-formula

I would like to import the following table with  elements in gsheets with the `importxml` function or any other suitable.

The url is https://racemap.com/timing/olympus-mythical-trail_2023-03-13, but I cannot find a way to import the table using the formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://racemap.com/timing/olympus-mythical-trail_2023-03-13"; "//div[contains(@class, 'ReactVirtualized__Grid multigrid-left')]")
```

Any ideas on how this can be done? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the table is generated using JavaScript, unfortunately `IMPORTXML` only gets the code source *before* it gets changed by JS.

For example, using a broader selector shows the data that it can get you, that table is not included:

```js
=IMPORTXML("https://racemap.com/timing/olympus-mythical-trail_2023-03-13", "/")
```

```js
Admin » Racemap  (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) { i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; (i[r] = 
i[r] || function () { (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments); }), (i[r].l 
= 1 * new Date()); (a = s.createElement(o)), (m = 
s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]); a.async = 1; a.src = g; 
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m); })(window, document, 'script', 
'//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga'); ga('create', '', 'auto'); 
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true); ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I found [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76154428/19602805) that gives more context on this behavior of `IMPORTXML` and similar formulas.

Comment: Thank you @Bryan Monterrosa. This was a good point to start with. I'll see what I can do.